# Warning and Fatal error updating from 4.6 to 4.7 com_civicrm/admin/configure.php on line 115

Tags: joomla, upgrade, 4.7

(Site information/versions at the bottom)
I have only used CiviCRM for event registration and entering other events in the calendar. More recently in anticipation of implementing membership capabilities, I had updated to the most recent version 4.6.11 and everything appeared fine. I received a message about running the update on the database and I did that. Everything was fine. But then when I logged on yesterday, I saw that 4.7 was out, so I went ahead and attempted to update to that version. I first just got the white screen. I went ahead and tried to reinstall the 4.6.11 version and got the following message:

> Warning: require_once(/home/hobbits8/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hobbits8/public_html/tmp/com_civicrm/admin/configure.php on line 115
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/hobbits8/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/hobbits8/public_html/tmp/com_civicrm/admin/configure.php on line 115

I tried uninstalling the component and reinstalling again, but once I uninstalled the component, I no longer had the menu entry for CiviCRM. I also followed the instructions for modifying the php (global settings off--already off, max upload--already at recommended level, time --I modified from 30 to 600). I've tried installing both the old (4.6.11) and the new (4.7) from a file upload and also from the tmp folder on the server and get the same result. I saw something about needing to compare settings with the old backup, and of course (dummy that I am), I do not have a backup.

I see someone asked a similar question, but the response to him did not fit either his or my scenario (not upgrading from an old version of Joomla or even an old version of CiviCRM).

- Joomla 3.4.8
- PHP 5.3.29
- mySQL 5.5.45 (innoDB enabled)

Thank you.
Patti

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the `civicrm.settings.php` file may have been removed when the upgrade/downgrade was applied to your site? See [Upgrading CiviCRM for Joomla](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Joomla#UpgradingCiviCRMforJoomla-2.BackupyourCiviCRMdatabaseandsettingsfile) in the section "Back up your CiviCRM database and settings file". Hopefully you have a copy of the file in your backup, and can restore it to the appropriate location.

CiviCRM recommends [PHP 5.4 or greater](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements), which might have caused the white screens when you tried 4.7. PHP 5.6 is the oldest supported PHP version at time of writing; as [versions 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 are no longer supported versions of PHP](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), I'd recommend updating your PHP if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Even though somewhere it said I had PHP 5.3.29, when I went into the area where I can change it, it was already at 5.4. I was able to get a restore from the hosting service, so I'm back where I was before. I'm going to test the update off the main site before proceeding. 

Patti